# Removing Double Quotes and Square Brackets JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am retrieving info from Amazon API with my server file (node.js)

```
client.itemLookup({
  idType: 'ISBN',
  itemId: 'B00S51XHUQ, B00P3IX4V6',
  responseGroup: 'Offers,ItemAttributes'
}).then(function(results){
    res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
  console.log(results);
})
```

Then I use `<td ng-repeat="att in amazon.ItemAttributes" >{{att.Title}}</td>`
to display some data from the app.get but it displays like this

["Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4 DRAM 2400MHz (PC4-19200) C14 Memory Kit - Black"]

with "" and [] around the data, I tried with .replace but no luck

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Ee8Aryw3

Any Ideas, Thank You

Comment: What does amazon.ItemAttributes look like? Can you log it and add the structure of the data to the question

Comment: Sorry its a big JSON file, added a paste bin

Comment: Why are you stringifying the JSON? That could be why you think you have to deal with these characters. If you are getting JSON it should only be displaying the text not the brackets and quotes around it.

Comment: Sorry, that was testing, it still does the same with res.send(results);

Comment: Is the resulting "att.Title" an array with 1 element then?  Maybe try {{arr.Title[0]}}

Comment: haha jesus.... thank you Jon

Answer (score 0):

Use a `$filter` with `.slice()`.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
 $scope.item = "[\"Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4 DRAM 2400MHz (PC4-19200) C14 Memory Kit - Black\"]";
  
  //$scope.hello = "hello world";
}]);

app.filter("cleanItem", function() {
 return function(input) {
   if(!input) return "";
    
    return input.slice(2, -2);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
{{item | cleanItem}}
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the JSON. Its a bit bigger that that.

Comment: The same principle applies:  You'd still use a custom filter:  `<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name | cleanItem }}</div>`

Comment: I would be pulling say 50 items out of the query? i would have to do this for each one?

Comment: Sorry, I understand your answer a bit better now, but when running it i  just get [] is that because you have \\ at each end?

Answer (score 0):

this is the filter for remove some chars:

```
 app.filter('clearText', function() {
        return function(text) {
          return  text ? String(text).replace(/"<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
       }
      });
```

in your html:

```
{{item | clearText}}
```